# How to show data in textview from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I'm still learning programming. I have problems with showing my data from firebase into a textview. My output is not showing the value from the database. This is my database from realtime [db realtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgFR4.png)

This is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView status,water,steam,inlet,outlet;
    String istatus,iwater,isteam,iinlet,ioutlet;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // address the text
        status = findViewById(R.id.a);
        water = findViewById(R.id.b);
        steam = findViewById(R.id.c);
        inlet = findViewById(R.id.d);
        outlet = findViewById(R.id.e);

        final DatabaseReference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ESP32_SADS");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                status.setText(istatus);
                water.setText(iwater);
                steam.setText(isteam);
                inlet.setText(iinlet);
                outlet.setText(ioutlet);

                istatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                iwater = dataSnapshot.child("Water").getValue().toString();
                isteam = dataSnapshot.child("Steam").getValue().toString();
                iinlet = dataSnapshot.child("Inlet").getValue().toString();
                ioutlet = dataSnapshot.child("Outlet").getValue().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

My output looks like this:
[image: output]

Comment: Hi, Can you debug and check whether you are getting data from db? write logs for both onDataChange() and onCancelled(). And see which one is getting invoked.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do it get value from db and then set it in your textView

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView status,water,steam,inlet,outlet;
    String istatus,iwater,isteam,iinlet,ioutlet;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // address the text
        status = findViewById(R.id.a);
        water = findViewById(R.id.b);
        steam = findViewById(R.id.c);
        inlet = findViewById(R.id.d);
        outlet = findViewById(R.id.e);

        final DatabaseReference ref 
        =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ESP32_SADS");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // your variables become have value then put it to your text
                istatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                iwater = dataSnapshot.child("Water").getValue().toString();
                isteam = dataSnapshot.child("Steam").getValue().toString();
                iinlet = dataSnapshot.child("Inlet").getValue().toString();
                ioutlet = dataSnapshot.child("Outlet").getValue().toString();

                // set values in textViews
                status.setText(istatus);
                water.setText(iwater);
                steam.setText(isteam);
                inlet.setText(iinlet);
                outlet.setText(ioutlet);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }



        });
    }
```

wrong part in your code , you write first before read

Comment: thanks for answering... i change the code but still the same

Comment: to test it change value in firebase db to enter in this method  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)  @syahmi ami